# How can I find and set the system PATH using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Why does the registry provider not show any entries for the environment? I am using "Run as Administrator". No items are returned from Get-ChildItem. What am I missing?

```
PS C:\src\t> ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] “Administrator”)
True
PS C:\src\t> Set-Location 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\'
PS HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\> Get-ChildItem
PS HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\>
```

Comment: Try `Get-ItemProperty`.

Comment: Ok. I see it. `Path` is a property of `Environment`. It would just seem logical that the provider would present `Path` as a child item of `Environment`.

Comment: `(Get-ItemProperty .).Path`

Comment: Use `GCI Env:` for all of your environment variables (including path)